# Insert rows depending on select query return

Tags: sql

i have a table user activity  ( iuser_id, sactivity)
I would need to insert multiple instances to this table using  user id ids from table user whose job is X . How do I do that?

```
Insert into tbluseractivity
(Select iuser_id from tbl_user where activity = x , 'sample activity')
```

Given that tbl_user would return 100 records, how can insert it.thank you.

Comment: do you want to insert all 100 records?

Comment: Yes all 100 of them

Comment: check my answer

Comment: This question is likely duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bulk insert as below

```
insert into tbluseractivity(iuser_id, sactivity)
Select iuser_id, 'sample activity' 
from tbl_user 
where activity = x
```

Comment: Thank you. I never thought it would be that simple